# Logical Volume Group "Available Space"

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

Can anyone help explain why there is 17gb worth of free space on my LVG I can't seem to do anything with this space. Is there anyway to fix this? I have already reformatted the disk then cloned the contents back with CCC. I also have FileVault enabled.

Whenever I see this on others setups it is usually a few KB not 17gb!

[image]

Comment: Can you please open Terminal and edit this question to show us the output of the `diskutil list` command?

Comment: I have attached it as an image.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas its driving me insane!

Answer (score 0):

You may be [not] seeing the other partitions on the drive, Recovery & EFI, which will be contributing to that 'extra' space.

Try enabling the debug menu in Disk Utility, then enabling all partition view…

1. Quit Disk Utility
2. Open the Terminal utility
3. Run the following Command:
   `defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1`
4. Relaunch Disk Utility
5. In the new Debug menu, enable 'Show every partition'
6. check if EFI & Recovery add up to the 'missing' space
   For me, EFI is tiny, approx 200MB, but Recovery is approx 1.2GB
   I don't have an LVG, so there may be a 4th partition governing that.

Comment: My FileVault drive has 8MB free space available. There's no way the free space reported has anything to do with the extra partitions. Recovery is about 650MB for me (at least on a 128GB drive. It may be larger on larger drives. No idea.) Core Storage doesn't actually add any partitions. It requires a recovery partition, but that's the normal setup these days anyway.

Comment: I checked this earlier and the hidden partitions make up for about 1gb of space!